# How to use cwise operations over specific indexes of a vector? (Eigen)

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to translate the following Matlab code to C/C++.

```
indl = find(dlamu1 < 0);  indu = find(dlamu2 < 0);
s = min([1; -lamu1(indl)./dlamu1(indl); -lamu2(indu)./dlamu2(indu)]);
```

I've read on another thread that there's yet no equivalent in the Eigen library to the `find()` function and I'm at peace with that and have brute-forced around it.

Now, if I wanted to do the coefficient-wise division of `lamu1` and `dlamu1`, I'd go for `lamu1.cwiseQuotient(dlamu1)` but how do I go about doing that but only for some of their coefficients, which indexes are specified by the coefficients of `indl`? I haven't found anything about this in the documentation, but maybe I'm not using the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default branch you can just write `lamu1(indl)` with `indl` a `std::vector<int>` or a `Eigen::VectorXi` or whatever you like that supports random access through `operator[]`.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like 
    lamu1(indl).cwiseQuotient(dlamu1(indl))?

Comment: Exactly, and to make my comment long enough for SO, I'll also write the variant: `lamu1(indl).array() / dlamu1(indl).array()`

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of `find` (yet) even in the default branch. Your function can however be expressed using the `select` method (also works with Eigen 3.3.x):

```
double ret1 = (dlamu1.array()<0).select(-lamu1.cwiseQuotient(dlamu1), 1.0).minCoeff();
return std::min(1.0,ret1); // not necessary, if dlamu1.array()<0 at least once
```

`select` evaluates lazily, i.e., only if the condition is true, the quotient will be calculated. On the other hand, a lot of unnecessary comparisons with 1.0 will happen with the code above.

If `[d]lamu` are stored in `Eigen::ArrayXd` instead of `Eigen::VectorXd`, you can write:

```
double ret1 = (dlamu1<0).select(-lamu1/dlamu1, 1.0).minCoeff();
```

If you brute-forced `indl` anyway, you can as ggael suggested write:

```
lamu1(indl).cwiseQuotient(dlamu1(indl)).minCoeff();
```

(this is undefined/crashes if `indl.size()==0`)

Comment: Both first and second suggestion result in seg.fault. As for ggael's suggestion it seems the compiler takes issue with it; I've tried replacing the type of indl from VectorXi to Index but once that is done the compiler then complains about the usage of "array()".

Comment: Code compiles and runs fine for me. What are the types of `dlamu1` and `lamu1` in your case? What Eigen version are you using? What compiler and what compilation options are you using? In other words: Provide a [mcve]!

Comment: Both are VectorXd. I'm using Eigen 3.3.5 and compiling using
     `g++ -std=c++11`